# Run and dispose Docker images on Azure

Tags: azure, docker

I would like to run Docker images on Azure on demand to do some processing.

What is the most cost-effective to do this in Azure to avoid keeping VMs up and running which are not being used? I could create and remove them manually but this is a task that will have to be done many times.

Is there a way to schedule a task that will create a Virtual Machine/Docker image, do the required processing and dispose itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at using [Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/container-instances/). These are standalone containers, that don't require creation of VM#s or Kubernetes clusters and you are just charged for when they are running.

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what I need!

Comment: Unfortunately I just saw ACI has the downside that it has a size limitation of 4vCPUs and 16GB of RAM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#can-i-deploy-with-more-than-4-cores-and-16-gb-of-ram I guess if I need a bigger size, I would have to manually write a script to deploy the Docker image, create and delete the VM after it completes.

Comment: Yes, it does have some limits, but you didn't mention your requirements in that area. If you need bigger then yes you would need to do something with a VM. Ideally you'd make your container requirements smaller, and run more of them.